# C# Memorystream is not fully saved to the file

Tags: c#, streamwriter, memorystream

I am exporting an object to csv using `MemoryStream` and `StreamWriter`. But after saving the file, I see that the end of the file is missing. Its cut of in the middle of a line.

Below is my code:

```
public void Export(ProductExport productExport)
{
    var country = (Country)(int.Parse(productExport.Firma.Code));

    using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);

        // Write header row
        sw.WriteLine(
            "{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9}",
            "Groep",
            "TecDoc Leverancier",
            "TecDoc Ref",
            "SA",
            "EAN",
            "Omschrijving NL",
            "V/E",
            "VPE",
            "Prijs per",
            "Bruto prijs"
        );

        foreach(var product in productExport.Products)
        {
            // Write header row
            sw.WriteLine(
                "{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8};{9}",
                product.Artgrp,
                product.TecDoc != null ? product.TecDoc.Supplier : "",
                product.TecDoc != null ? product.TecDoc.Value : "",
                product.Ids.Where<Id>(i => i.Type == "SA").Select(i => i.Value).DefaultIfEmpty("").First(),
                product.Ids.Where<Id>(i => i.Type == "EN").Select(i => i.Value).DefaultIfEmpty("").First(),
                product.Descriptions.Where<Description>(d => d.Lang == "NL").Select(i => i.Value).DefaultIfEmpty("").First(),
                product.SalesUnit,
                product.PackingUnit.Value,
                product.PriceUnit.Value,
                product.Prices.First<Price>(p => p.Type == "BR" && p.Country == country.ToString()).Value
            );
        }

        FileSystem.AddFile(country + "-" + String.Format("{0:yyyyMMdd}", DateTime.Now) + ".csv", stream);

        sw.Flush();
    }
}
```

And this is the code of the `FileSystem.AddFile()` function:

```
public void AddFile(string path, System.IO.Stream stream)
{
    var fullPath = GetFullPath(path);

    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath);
    if (directory == null) throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't get the directory.");
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory); // Make sure the directory is created!

    if (stream.CanSeek)
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    using (var destination = (Stream)File.Create(fullPath))
        stream.CopyTo(destination);
}
```

Comment: First `sw.Flush();`, then `FileSystem.AddFile`. The `StreamWriter` could be buffering before outputting.

Comment: @Xanatos thanks worked like a charm!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First `sw.Flush()`, then do the `FileSystem.AddFile()`. The `StreamWriter` is probably buffering the output before passing it to the `MemoryStream`.

Comment: This could also be fixed by putting the `StreamWriter` in a using statement, since that will ensure that it gets disposed which will also flush any internal buffering it's doing.

Comment: @Kyle Yes, but you must remember to pass `true` as the `leaveOpen` parameter of the constructor of `StreamWriter`, otherwise the SW will close the underlying stream on closing/disposing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to flush the `StreamWriter` first and then create the file from the stream.